# How may I use regular expressions with fzf?

Tags: regular-expression, fzf

In vim for example, you search names like `test1`, `test2` or `test9` if you
press `/\<test\d\>`. I'd like to have this "feature" like finding filesnames
which have the word `test<num>` in their filename. I tried it out:

[image]

But it doesn't work, as you can see.

Here are my FZF-Environment-Variables:

- $FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND
  `rg --files --hidden --glob "!.git/*"`
- $FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS
  `--prompt=' ' --cycle --preview='bat {}' +i --bind=ctrl-j:preview-half-page-down,ctrl-k:preview-half-page-up`

How can I use the regex patterns like in vim and sed to find files (and if it's
possible to find words in these files)?

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: Can I only use these three characters? `!`, `$`, `^`? @mattb

Comment: hm... ok, could you write your comment as an answer please so I can tick this question as answered?

Comment: Answer posted. Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if this is possible with fzf. But it does have a couple of special
characters like `^` (must start with), `$` (must end with), `!` (must not
contain). As for searching within files, you can do this with either the
[silver searcher (ag)](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) or [rigrep (rg)](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) assuming they're installed by
using the commands `:Ag` or `:Rg`

You can also take advantage of adding multiple patterns, each one delimited
with spaces: e.g. `^core .py$ !test` will match files that begin with 'core'
and end with '.py'. and do not contain 'test' You can keep adding more patterns
to narrow the search results.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the accepted answer, I want to add that ***spaces in your search pattern matter too***, in order to separate fuzzy search pattern arguments.

Let's say you have this file tree. Notice that each dir has a `test.txt` and `test` file in it:

```
temp/dir1/test.txt
temp/dir1/test

temp/dir2/test.txt
temp/dir2/test

temp/dir3/test.txt
temp/dir3/test
```

Let's try to find all 3 files above which have the search pattern `temp` somewhere in their path, *and* are named `test` and have *no file extension*:

In default search mode in `fzf`:

1. This search will find **no files**:

   ```bsh
   temp/test$
   ```
2. This search will find **all 6 files**:

   ```bsh
   temp/test
   ```
3. So, if you're trying to find *just the `test` files which have no extension*, you must *add a space into your search pattern*, like this! This search will find **just the 3 `test` files** which have no file extension (and have the pattern `temp` somewhere higher up in the path):

   ```bsh
   temp /test$
   ```

Adding that one space between the two fuzzy search patterns (`temp` and `/test$`) makes all the difference!

Note that this search too will find all 6 files:

```bsh
temp /test
```

In summary, to find just the 3 `test` files with no extension, you must *use the space to separate fuzzy search parameters*, AND use the `$` at the end to indicate "end of line":

```bsh
temp /test$
```

Of course, the same requirement for the space between fuzzy search parameters applies to the `^` "beginning of line" search character too. (This example doesn't make this point well, but the principle is the same.):

```bsh
^temp /test
```